# Why are my GarageBand loops moving weirdly?

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, garageband

For some reason everytime I try to move a loop along a track in GarageBand, it either moves a little bit forward, backward, or not at all. I'll click and drag the loop from one end of the track to the other and it'll move like 1 beat forward or back, and has no correlation to how far I drag. **Can someone please explain why this is happening, and how I can work around it? Also, is this a bug related to MacOS Beta?**

If it helps, I a using a 2015 MacBook Air running MacOS 10.12.2 Developer Beta 4.

EDIT: I have tried turning on and off the snapping, and "catch the playhead".

Comment: disable "Snapping" to the tempo? Don't use garageband, but that's the first thing I would check, since DAW software often defaults to it being on.

Comment: @Yorik, I have added an edit to my post